# Deduction of instancetype by LLVM compiler

Tags: objective-c, llvm

I have this piece of code:

```
@interface Bar : UIView
- (id)initWithInt:(int)i;
@end

@implementation Bar
- (id)initWithInt:(int)i {
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}
@end

void func() {
  [[[Bar alloc] initWithInt:10] doSomething];
}
```

The compiler gives me an error in the func() function: No visible @Interface for Bar declares the selector doSomething.
I do have another @interface with the method doSomething.
The compiler somehow assumed that initWithInt: returns instancetype rather than id.
What are the rules to this? In what cases does a compiler assume that a method returns instancetype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In what cases does a compiler assume that a method returns
>   instancetype?

That is documented in ["CLANG LANGUAGE EXTENSIONS"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html):

> According to Cocoa conventions, Objective-C methods with certain names
>   (“init”, “alloc”, etc.) always return objects that are an instance of
>   the receiving class’s type. Such methods are said to have a “related
>   result type”, meaning that a message send to one of these methods will
>   have the same static type as an instance of the receiver class.
>
> ...
>
> To determine whether a method has an inferred related result type, the first word in the 
>   camel-case selector (e.g., “init” in “initWithObjects”) is considered,
>   and the method will have a related result type if its return type is
>   compatible with the type of its class and if:
>
> - the first word is “alloc” or “new”, and the method is a class method,
> - or the first word is “autorelease”, “init”, “retain”, or “self”, and
>     the method is an instance method.

So your `initWithInt:` method has a "inferred related result type", and
therefore the compiler assumes that it returns an instance of `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

don't know BUT

inits always should return instance types anyways. it is only logical. I cannot imagine any other situation.

Just import the subclass that declares doSomething and you're good

Answer (score 0):

> I do have another @interface with the method doSomething.

Each class must have exactly one `@interface` (although you can make class extension, categories, etc. to add further methods).  If your `-doSomething` method is in a category (or class extension) in another file, make sure that its declaration is visible in this file via an `#import`.